# Group homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group and ${\rm Aut}(G)$ its associated automorphism group. Prove that the function
$$i:\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow{\rm Aut}(G)$$
given by
$$i_0(h)=h,\;\;\;i_1(h)=h^{-1},$$
where $h \in G$, is a group homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian. I can't seem to figure out where to go with this question. If $i$ is a homomorphism, then
$$i_0=i(0) = i(2) = i(1+1) = i(1)+i(1) =i_1\circ i_1$$
Similar equalities like this hold, but I don't see how they depend on $G$ being abelian. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that $i_1$ won't even be a homomorphism unless $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I should have noticed that! Thank you!